# Specifying interactions in python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have independent variables [x1,...x50] where x1-x10 is one set of variables (medication) and x11-x50 denote the presence/absence of a specific mutation.
The dependent variable is a score.

I want to perform a regression that allows me to see the coefficient of a subset of these interactions,(to find the affect of a medication/mutation pair on the score) ie: (x1:x11, x1:x12,...x1:50, x2:x11, x2:x12,...x2:50,..........,x10:x11, x10:x12,...x10:50)

I have used sklearns' PolynomialFeatures and fit_transform

`poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True)`

`data = poly.fit_transform(x)`

and subsequently used ElasticNetCV as the model

`regr = ElasticNetCV(cv=5, random_state=0)`

`regr.fit(x, y)`

My question is how do I set the subset of coefficients that I am interested in?
Also. I would welcome opinions on the suitability of my ML approach

Comment: You should be able to inspect the feature names to find the indices of the `coef_` that interest you?

Comment: Hi. Silly question, but how do you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

With `med_vars` and `mut_vars` being lists containing the relevant column names:

```py
coef_dict = dict(zip(poly.get_feature_names_out(), regr.coef_))
cross_terms = [f"{a} {b}" for a in med_vars for b in mut_vars]  # itertools might be better, esp. if you had more groups
coefs_of_interest = {key: coef_dict[key] for key in cross_terms}
```

I did an example with the iris dataset: [notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO74368088.ipynb)

Comment: Hi. I actually implemented something similar here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595214/372367